# Hiding previous element by checked selector

Tags: css

I would like to use css3 features to hiding previous element.

Basically,

I want to use a checkbox to hide previous sibling element without using javascript.

I have prepared a sample for entry point.

http://cssdesk.com/5zccy

Thanks

Edit:

- I have changed sample.
- My usecase: I want to have collapsible sections at my site. Two area separated by a simple checkbox and checking it will beautifully hide previous sibling.

I believe that using pure css will let me to reduce using javascript for this task.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What previous element, the parent?

Comment: Updated my question. Sorry for the confusion about parent/child relationship instead of sibling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not hide the previous elements - just the following ones with the [general sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector)

[**DEMO**](http://cssdesk.com/qZ8AM)

Then you might be able to position the elements, so on the actual page the checkbox will appear after the `.parent` div.

Answer (score 0):

There's no css selector to select the previous tag of a matched element. The closest you can get using only css it's doing that for the next element:

```
<input class="hider" type="checkbox" /> child
<div class="parent">
    Parent
</div>​

.hider:checked + * {
    display:none;
}​
```